# Exported attribute not found in terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a role that once assumed should provide access to a specific bucket to certain users outside the AWS account

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "s3_role_access" {
  name               = "${var.s3_role_name}"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.template_file.iam_policy_s3_assume.rendered}"
  description        =  "Role providing access to ${var.s3_role_bucket_name}/${var.s3_role_bucket_path}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "s3_role_access" {
  name   = "${var.s3_role_name}"
  role   = "${aws_iam_role.s3_role_access.id}"
  policy = "${data.template_file.iam_policy_s3_permissions.rendered}"
}
```

I'm expecting the plan to succeed but I am getting the following:

> Error: Error running plan: 1 error occurred:
>           * module.xxx.aws_iam_role_policy.s3_role_access: 1 error occurred:
>           * module.xxx.aws_iam_role_policy.s3_role_access: Resource 'aws_iam_role.s3_role_access' not found for variable
>   'aws_iam_role.s3_role_access.id'

The id attribute should be exported as described at  https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role.html#id

Comment: This error can also be thrown when the resource exporting the attribute is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the JSON passed in the policy was not rendering properly.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an error during creating aws_iam_role.s3_role_access, sometimes terraform doesn't show the error properly and show above error during creating aws_iam_role_policy.s3_role_access like above because there is no aws_iam_role resource.

in that case, you can check the aws_iam_role.s3_role_access after comment out aws_iam_role_policy resource for testing.